# initialize a form with condition

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I want to use a form depending on the results returned by a service, in my example if the conventions list is not null it calls the method initFormWithRequiredConvention, but the problem is that the list of conventions in the controller is undefined and in the HTML, the list of the convention is displayed

```
public conventions: Convention[];

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private conventionService: ConventionService) {
    if(this.conventions)
       this.initFormWithRequiredConvention();
    else
       this.initFormWithoutRequiredConvention();
}

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.conventionService.getAll().subscribe((datas: any) => {
        this.conventions = datas.content;
    });
}

private initFormWithRequiredConvention(): void {
    const fb = this.fb;
    this.networkForm = this.fb.group({
        abstractName: fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        conventionsId: this.fb.array([
            this.fb.control(null, Validators.compose([Validators.required]))
        ])
    });
}

private initFormWithoutRequiredConvention(): void {
    const fb = this.fb;
    this.networkForm = this.fb.group({
        abstractName: fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        completeName: fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        countryId: fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        conventionsId: this.fb.array([
            this.fb.control(null)
        ])
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the basic difference between `constructor` and `ngOnInit`.

A `Constructor` is a special type of method of a class and it will be automatically invoked when an instance of the class is created.

`ngOnInit` is a  lifecycle hook offered by Angular that Angular calls shortly after creating the component.

The order of execution is `Constructor-> ngOnInit`

1. The `if-else` block inside the constructor is redundant
   `if(this.conventions)` will never evaluate to true.
2. you are invoking your `getAll()` method in `ngOnInit` subscribing it extracting the response and that's it what are you doing with it?? If you assumed `constructor` would be invoked again you are wrong.

use the constructor to invoke your default case.

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private conventionService:ConventionService){
this.initFormWithoutRequiredConvention();
}
```

Move your logic inside subscribe once it gets the result, appropriate method will be executed

```
`public ngOnInit(): void {
            this.conventionService.getAll().subscribe((datas: any) => {
                this.conventions = datas.content;

              if(this.conventions)
                  this.initFormWithRequiredConvention();
              else
                   this.initFormWithoutRequiredConvention();
            });
        }`
```